# What is the servlet's init() method used for?

Tags: java, servlets

When I decompile the GenericServlet and check the  init() , I see the following code .

```
public void init(ServletConfig servletconfig)
    throws ServletException
{
    config = servletconfig;
    init();
}

public void init()
    throws ServletException
{
}
```

What is the init method actually doing here ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: most servletcontainers are open source. You can just download the source code of your servletcontainer from their homepage. It includes the Servlet API. No need to manually decompile it :)

Comment: @BalusC you can, but it's a tedious process. For quick "check what this thing does" I prefer decompilation as well.

Comment: @Bozho: decompiled sources does not contain javadocs. It's maybe an tedious one-time task, but after that you can just include the source in your IDE and you've never have to face an "unknown source" page and/or decomplile every little class individually.

Comment: @BalusC yes, for things like the servlet API (or spring, for example. I have both downloaded actually) it's worth having the code. But I have 60 other dependencies - decompilation + googling for documentation works better :)

Comment: @Bozho: I think immediately downloading the source along the dependency or using Maven/Git works better :) Personal preference.

Comment: @BalusC - I still have some questions about the `init()` method vs servlet constructor. Why can't we put all the initialization/init code inside the servlet constructor ? Actually, my book asks the question this way - `Why is there an init() method? In other words, why isn't the constructor enough for intializing a servlet? What kind of code would you put in the init() method`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29):

```
/**
 *
 * A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need
 * to call <code>super.init(config)</code>.
 *
 * <p>Instead of overriding {@link #init(ServletConfig)}, simply override
 * this method and it will be called by
 * <code>GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config)</code>.
 * The <code>ServletConfig</code> object can still be retrieved via {@link
 * #getServletConfig}. 
 *
 * @exception ServletException  if an exception occurs that
 *                  interrupts the servlet's
 *                  normal operation
 *
 */
```

So it does nothing and is just a convenience.

Comment: Why can't we put all the initialization/init code inside the servlet constructor ? Actually, my book asks the question this way - `Why is there an init() method? In other words, why isn't the constructor enough for intializing a servlet? What kind of code would you put in the init() method`.

Comment: _Well, in JDK 1.0 (for which servlets were originally written), constructors for dynamically loaded Java classes (such as servlets) couldn't accept arguments. So, in order to provide a new servlet any information about itself and its environment, a server had to call a servlet's init() method and pass along an object that implements the ServletConfig interface_  - Java Servlet Programming by Jason Hunter with William Crawford

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it does nothing. It could have been abstract, but then each servlet would be forced to implement it. This way, by default, nothing happens on `init()`, and each servlet can override this behaviour. For example, you have two servlets:

```
public PropertiesServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private Properties properties;

   @Override
   public void init() {
       // load properties from disk, do be used by subsequent doGet() calls
   }
}
```

and

```
public AnotherServlet extends HttpServlet {

   // you don't need any initialization here, 
   // so you don't override the init method.
}
```

Comment: But no requests are served until the init() method is called . If nothing happens in the init method , what is the point ?

Comment: Your servlet can override this and specify what should happen

Comment: @Bozho - Why can't we put all the initialization/init code inside the servlet constructor ? Actually, my book asks the question this way - `Why is there an init() method? In other words, why isn't the constructor enough for intializing a servlet? What kind of code would you put in the init() method`.

Comment: @Bozho - I read my book further and it says that init method gives access to the `ServletConfig` and `Servletcontext` objects, which the servlet needs to get information about the servlet configuration and the web app. `MY QUESTION IS - ` How can that be possible ? `init()` has no code in its body.

Answer (score 4):

Constructor might not have access to `ServletConfig` since container have not called `init(ServletConfig config)` method.

`init()` method is inherited from `GenericServlet` which has a `ServletConfig` as its property. thats how `HttpServlet`and what ever custom servlet you write by extending `HttpServlet` gets `ServletConfig`.

and  `GenericServlet` implements `ServletConfig` which has `getServletContext` method. so your custom servlets `init` method will have access to both of those.

Answer (score 3):

Servlet container calls servlet `init()` method before handling client requests. It is called just one times after servlet is created. By default it does nothing. You can override this method and it is also good for performing one-time activities. Such as database connection or reading configuration data etc.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
     super.init(config);

     // You can define your initial parameter in web.xml file.
     String initialParameter = config.getInitParameter("initialParameter");
     // Do some stuff with initial parameters

}
```

**What happens if init() method throw an exception?**

The servlet `destroy()` will not be called because it is unsuccesfull initialization. Servlet container may try to instantiate and initialize a new instance of this failed servlet later.

Answer (score -1):

Who said init method do nothing. It's use for one time servlet initialization of variable etc. For example you can put PreparedStatement initialization in there. So that the next call of the servlet, there is no need anymore for PS initialization. You must know that init is part of Servlet lifecycle.

The first time the servlet loaded in Glassfish or Tomcat, the init method will be called and servlet stays in memory of the application server. The subsequent call will execute servlet and the init method will not be called. However the variable initialization is there, already initialized.

The init() method simply creates (once only) and loads some data that will be used throughout the life of the servlet.